# Обратится к полю объекта через переменную

Tags: php, веб-программирование, ооп, классы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как то обратится к полю объекта класса, через поле другого класса не создавая новых переменных?

Т.е. Сейчас у меня есть класс ***Test***, в котором есть поле с именем ***pole_name*** и методом ***wokr_object($obj)***.

Метод ***wokr_object*** получает объект ***$obj***, у которого есть поле, имя которого соответствует значению хранимому в поле ***pole_name***.

И мне в функции ***wokr_object*** нужно обратиться к этому полю.
У меня получился вот такой код:

```
public function wokr_object($obj){ 
    $temp = $this->pole_name;
    echo $obj->$temp;
}
```

Это вроде работает, но мне не нравится, что приходится создавать дополнительную переменную темп, хочется как то в одну строку написать.

Т.е. хочется написать что-то вроде `echo $obj->$this->pole_name` - но это не работает, выводит ошибку.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как то это поправить, может скобки как-то расставить?

Comment: Приведите вопрос, пожалуйста, в подобающий вид. С помощью имеющегося визивинга можно достойно оформить то что сейчас имеется.

Comment: @borodatych вы, как участник сообщества, робеющий за внешнее оформление, можете вполне спокойно нажать "править" и подформатировать вопрос, тем самым помочь и новичку и остальным)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```
echo $obj->{$this->pole_name};
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Я не додумался до фигурных скобок, пытался в круглые вставить, но с круглыми выдавало ошибку. Если не сложно можете подсказать, почему с фигурными скобками ошибок не вылетает, а круглые в такой конструкции вызывают ошибку?

Comment: @ВладимирВладимир круглые скобки для математических логических операций, а фигурные скобки помогают интерпретатору четко понять где начало переменной, а где конец.......... посмотрите http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php  раздел `Сложный (фигурный) синтаксис`

Comment: Фигурные скобки используются, т.к. здесь происходит обращение к свойству не напрямую, а через составное имя.
Круглые просто указывают приоритет действий, их можно использовать, например, при конкатенации строк, при вычислении или в условиях, но не при обращении.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: За что минус влепили, хочется узнать?

Comment: хоть это все и работает и да правильно. я минусую лишь за то что это 1. усложняет восприятие кода как кода (код должен быть понятен и человеку и машине) 2. стремление к краткости пораждает 'тетрисы в одну строку' длиною в овер 1000 символов. 3. Отвечая на такие вопросы стоит подсказать как сделать так чтобы вот этот параметер класа небыл взят из метода другого класса, так как 2-3 класса и кучка методов, и понять что происходит и что от куда береться, даже автору составит труда...

Comment: Есть ваша правда, но явно не этот случай. А ответ кстати можете дополнить, будет полезно.

Comment: На самом деле, если я указал реализацию для данного случая, это еще не значит, что это пример для общего использования. Так то лучше использовать хотя бы те же getter'ы и setter'ы, а не вытаскивать свойства объекта напрямую.

Comment: @Daniel-664, не надо усложнять, ответ дан в точку.

Comment: В данном случае да.

Comment: Ответ в данном контексте дан. Но все же следует указать на явные недостатки такого метода в этом контексте. В конце концов обращение с переменной(говоряще названой) как минимум облегчает понимание.