# Зачем в PHP нужны фигурные скобки?

Tags: php

Какой смысл в данных фигурных скобках?

```
$obj->{$options['option.disable']} = $options['disable'];
```

Comment: а из этого кода не ясно зачем?

Comment: думаю это ваш случай [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510214/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510214/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php)

> К свойствам класса также можно получить доступ динамически. Переменное
>   имя свойства будет разрешено в том контексте, в котором произойдет
>   вызов к нему. Например, в случае выражения `$foo->$bar`, локальная
>   область видимости будет просканирована на наличие переменной `$bar`,
>   значение которой будет использовано в качестве имени свойства объекта
>   `$foo`. Это также работает и в том случае, если `$bar` осуществляет доступ
>   к элементу массива.
>
> Фигурные скобки могут также использоваться, чтобы четко разграничить
>   имя свойства. Они наиболее полезны при получении доступа к значениям
>   внутри свойства, которое содержит массив, когда имя свойства состоит
>   из нескольких частей, либо когда имя свойства содержит символы,
>   которые иначе не действительны (например, из функции `json_decode()` или
>   из `SimpleXML`).

Обычно фигурные скобки используются для динамического доступа к свойствам класса, то есть когда имя свойства содержится в переменной. В вашем случае, переменная содержащая имя свойства - массив. Поэтому запись без указания скобок будет  неоднозначна, т.к. не ясно вы хотите получить доступ к свойству-массиву с именем `$options` т.е. формально `($obj->options)['option.disable']`, либо все же `$options['option.disable']` содержит имя свойства.

В общем, скобки явным образом отделяют имя свойства. Наиболее часто такая запись используется для доступа к свойствам, когда их имена не соответствуют правилам именовнаия, т.е. например содержат дефис `$obj->{'some-property'}`. Такое может получится при десериализации объектов из json или xml.

Comment: спасибо ) Как раз хотел спросить, где используется такая запись, а когда дочитал ваш пост - увидел ответ :)